# simplexml_load_file(): http://website.com/feed:563: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, feed

I'm trying to load XML data from a website, But I'm getting the following errors:

```
simplexml_load_file(): http://website.com/feed:563: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
simplexml_load_file(): 00f0i\u00f0, vi\u00f0 h\u00f6fum m\u00f3tteki\u00f0 \u00fea\u00f0.\r\n\r\n&amp;nbsp;
```

Here is the code:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://website.com/feed');
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = (string)trim(strip_tags($item->title));
    $title = html_entity_decode($post['title']);
    $description = (string)trim(strip_tags($item->description));
}
```

I don't have access to edit the XML code, So how to solve this issue?

UPDATE: This is the 1st part of the RSS feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title></title>
    <atom:link href="" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 24 Feb 2021 12:12:53 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>
    hourly  </sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>
    1   </sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator></generator>

<image>
    <url></url>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <width>32</width>
    <height>32</height>
</image> 
    <item>
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[]]></dc:creator>
        <pubDate>Wed, 24 Feb 2021 11:00:20 +0000</pubDate>
                <category><![CDATA[]]></category>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>

                    <description><![CDATA[ [...]]]></description>
                                        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><strong></strong></p>
<p> <a href=""></a></p>
]]></content:encoded>
</item>
```

How to get the content from this code using PHP?

Comment: Are you sure that the response contains an XML RSS feed?

Comment: Yeah I viewed the link in browser it starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"`

Comment: I don't know XML, But I'm sure it's XML and rss feed

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not allowed in XML - only in (X)HTML.

Comment: What functions could work in this situation?

Comment: I updated the question and added part of the feed

Comment: The actual part is missing in your question to say more about. It looks like the feed is not XML (and in good faith as the original URL is not provided, we should assume so, that is what the error message is saying, which is provided). If you post replacement urls like `http://website.com/feed` in the question, please use `example.com`  (or `example.org`, `example.net` etc.) as that is the correct form for documentation. And the result of `trim()` is always a string, therefore you do not need to cast it (`(string)`).